# Unable to deploy Ubuntu 20.04 Docker container on Google Cloud Run

Tags: docker, ubuntu, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to deploy a simple Python-based Docker container based on Ubuntu 20.04 via Google Cloud Run. I've successfully built the image, but when I try to deploy the Cloud Run service, I get the following error (project details omitted):

```
Cloud Run error: Invalid argument error. Invalid ENTRYPOINT. [name: "gcr.io/{PROJECT_ID}/{SERVICE_NAME}@sha256:{HASH}"
error: "Invalid command \"/bin/sh\": fil
  e not found"
  e not found"
]....failed
Deployment failed
```

What's strange, though, is if I pull and run the image locally, it works just fine.

```
docker run --rm --publish 5000:5000 -e PORT=5000 -it gcr.io/{PROJECT_ID}/{SERVICE_NAME}@sha256:{HASH}
```

My Dockerfile is about as basic as it gets:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip \
    && pip3 install gunicorn Flask flask-cors

CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --worker-tmp-dir /dev/shm --timeout 900 wsgi:app
```

What's even stranger still is that if I replace the base image with `debian:buster-slim`, it works just fine.

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on?

---

Additional info:

```yaml
status:
  conditions:
  - type: Ready
    status: 'False'
    message: |-
      Cloud Run error: Invalid argument error. Invalid ENTRYPOINT. [name: "gcr.io/{PROJECT_ID}/{SERVICE_NAME}@sha256:{HASH}"
      error: "Invalid command \"/bin/sh\": file not found"
      ].
    lastTransitionTime: '2020-05-12T07:40:12.804Z'
  - type: ConfigurationsReady
    status: 'False'
    message: |-
      Cloud Run error: Invalid argument error. Invalid ENTRYPOINT. [name: "gcr.io/{PROJECT_ID}/{SERVICE_NAME}@sha256:{HASH}"
      error: "Invalid command \"/bin/sh\": file not found"
      ].
    lastTransitionTime: '2020-05-12T07:40:12.804Z'
  - type: RoutesReady
    status: 'True'
    lastTransitionTime: '2020-05-12T06:19:12.224Z'
```

Comment: Do you mind going to Cloud Console and looking at YAML tab of your Cloud Run service and add its `status` field to your question above. I expect the same error, but perhaps there are more details.

Comment: @AhmetB-Google as suspected, the errors in the status area are the same as what's being reported on the command line. Additionally, I don't seem to have any syslog entries in the Cloud Logging console, so I don't think it's a sandbox issue.

Comment: Does it work with this command?
gcloud run deploy --image gcr.io/PROJECT-ID/helloworld --platform managed

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue. It seems to be intermittent: in the day time I couldn't deploy to Cloud Run, but in the late evening, various workarounds worked about half the time.

The most reliable workaround I found is to not depend on /bin/sh or /bin/bash in CMD or ENTRYPOINT. It appears /bin/sh exists at runtime, but it sometimes doesn't exist while Cloud Run is testing the container before deployment.

Instead of this in Dockerfile:

```
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 4 main:app
```

I used this instead:

```
CMD ["/usr/bin/python3", "/app/run_gunicorn.py", "--workers", "1", "--threads", "4", "main:app"]
```

Then I added the run_gunicorn.py script:

```
import os
import sys
from gunicorn.app.wsgiapp import run
port = os.environ['PORT']
sys.argv[-1:-1] = ['--bind', f':{port}']
print("sys.argv:", sys.argv)
run()
```

That's a way to keep the port number dynamic.